# Apache Jena: riot does not produce output

Tags: jena

I recently installed Apache Jena 3.17.0, and have been trying to use it to convert nquads files to ntriples.

As per the instructions, here (https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tools/) I first set up my WSL (Ubuntu 20.04) environment

```
$ export JENA_HOME=apache-jena-3.17.0/
$ export PATH=$PATH:$JENA_HOME/bin
```

and then attempted to run riot to do the conversion (triail.nq is my nquads file).

```
$ riot --output=NTRIPLES -v triail.nq
```

When I ran this, I got no output to the terminal. I'm not sure what is going wrong here, since there is no error message. Does anyone know what could be causing this / what the solution could be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command will read the quad (multiple graph) data and output only the default graph. Presumably there is no default graph data in `triail.nq`.

If "convert" means combine all the quads into a single graph, then remove the graph field on each line of the data file with a text editor.

Otherwise, read into a RDF dataset and copy the named graphs into a single graph and output that.